# 'Now' as a preposition or conjunction

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

In the below sentence, is 'now' a preposition or a subordinating conjunction? Most dictionaries (OED, Webster, AHD, etc.) say that 'now' is a (subordinating) conjunction in the sense of the below sentence, but I am aware that some prepositions can take clausal complements; thus I am unsure whether 'now' in the sense below is a preposition licensing a content clause as a complement,or a conjunction (since dictionaries are not known to be the best sources for checking parts of speech).

> Now that we are all here, let us begin.

Comment: Your right that some prepositions take causal complements, but dictionaries take decades to write and often centuries to fully update. For this reason most dictionaries use 19th century grammar terminology and are not a good source of grammar information. Once you remove all the prepositions from the 19th century subordinating conjunction category, there are only 5 or so true subordinator left: *that, whether, if, for* and some uses of *how*. The word *now* in your example is indeed a preposition taking a clausal complement.

Comment: It's a preposition used deictically with a content clause complement specifying what distinguishes present time from the pre-now period.

Answer (score 4):

> *Now that we are all here, let us begin.*

I agree with Araucaria's comment.

It's a preposition used deictically with a content clause complement specifying what distinguishes present time from the pre-now period.

It can't be a conjunction, since "that" is an indisputable conjunction and two adjacent conjunctions are not permitted.

Comment: Re: "two adjacent conjunctions are not permitted": Consider "It is clear that [...], **and that** [...]".

Comment: @ruakh There's nothing to consider. They are not adjacent, but introduce two separate clauses each introduced by a conjunction.

Comment: If by "adjacent" you mean something other than "immediately preceding or following" (sense 1c at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjacent), could you provide some information about what you *do* mean by it?

Comment: @ruakh In your example the two ‘that’s at separated by the word ‘and’. Hence neither immediately preceded or follows the other.

Comment: Wake up @ruakh It's obvious what I meant. I explained in my previous comment that the two conjunctions in your example introduce separate clauses and hence are not adjacent in the same clause.

Comment: @Araucaria: Thanks, but I think you misread my comment. The two conjunctions that I bolded are not the two that's, but the conjunction "and" and the conjunction "that" that are directly adjacent to each other ("and that").

Comment: @BillJ: You knew what you meant even before writing it, so to you it seems obvious what you meant; but I don't have that advantage. (This sort of mistake is easy to make -- I thought the meaning of my comment was obvious, but as you can see, Araucaria misread it. So, rather than dickishly telling him/her to wake up, I simply clarified. I invite you to do the same.)

Comment: @ruakh Ah, Bill meant subordinators, not coordinators!

Comment: @Araucaria: Thanks! Nonetheless, consider "Well, I think **that whether** they are reasonable or not would depend very largely upon [...]" [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=5UdKAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA609&dq=that-whether)].

Comment: @ruakh Yes, there’s no doubt that they can be adjacent (was thinking about posting an example too). Bill’s right though that there can only be one per clause i.e. the same clause cannot have two different subordinators in Marker function.